# bundling error: syntax error Unexpected token while using React-native-android-wifi

Tags: react-native

I'm a beginner in react-native and want to manage the wifi in my android device. Basically, I want to ask permission to turn on wifi, show the wifi-list and disconnect the wifi, so I followed this tutorial:

- https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/react-native-manage-wifi-android

The code for asking permission below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

var wifi = require('react-native-android-wifi');

export default class App extends Component {

  wifi.isEnabled((isEnabled) => {
    if (isEnabled) {
      console.log("wifi service enabled");
    } else {
      console.log("wifi service is disabled");
    }
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

I got this error:

- [it says unexpected token and I have no idea about the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQsTI.png)

Could someone please help me out, why am I getting the error and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the fact that you need to call your `wifi.isEnabled` in your componentDidMount rather in the body of you class.

Update your component to be:

```
export default class App extends Component{

  componentDidMount() {
    wifi.isEnabled((isEnabled)=>{
      if (isEnabled){
       console.log("wifi service enabled");
      }else{
        console.log("wifi service is disabled");
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Looking at the repo for [react-native-android-wifi](https://github.com/BoTreeConsultingTeam/react-native-android-wifi) there are a few steps that you still need to do.

Firstly you need to request the permission to access the location. So let's do that in the `componentDidMount` as this is an async request we need to make sure that your `componentDidMount` is also async.

Secondly we want to perform the check. We can do this tying it into a button press.

We will also need to import a couple of things from `react-native`, since we are using the Button component and wanting to request permissions for Android.

```
import { Button, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

  async componentDidMount () {
    this.askForUserPermissions();
  }

  async askForUserPermissions () {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'Wifi networks',
          'message': 'We need your permission in order to find wifi networks'
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('Thank you for your permission! :)');
      } else {
        console.log('You will not able to retrieve wifi available networks list');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  }

  checkWiFi () {
    wifi.isEnabled((isEnabled) => {
      if (isEnabled) {
        console.log('wifi service enabled');
      } else{
        console.log('wifi service is disabled');
      }
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title={'check wifi'} onPress={this.checkWiFi.bind(this)} />
        <Text>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

For more details on how to set this up, look at the [examples](https://github.com/BoTreeConsultingTeam/react-native-android-wifi/tree/master/Examples) in the repo, they show how to do most of the things that you will probably want to do.

Comment: Hello there Mr.@Andrew! I got a problem. Whenever i get connected to a network, the  wifilist doesnot show other nearby wifi but shows only mine. I need to list all the nearby wifi either i am connected to a network or not.

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for the dependency. There is a method called `loadWifiList` look to the docs to see how to implement it. https://github.com/BoTreeConsultingTeam/react-native-android-wifi/blob/master/README.md